# What does SEG directive do in 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

`SEG A` :

`Assigns the content held in segment register corresponding to the segment in which A resides to the operand.`

I guess that means that if `A` lies in Data Segment, `SEG A` is the same as `DS`.

Since `DS` holds the base address of the Data Segment, does

```
MOV AX, LEA A
MOV DX, SEG A
MOV AX, [AX + DX]
```

copy the **physical address** of `A` to `AX`?

Comment: Please tag which assembler you're using (MASM, NASM, TASM...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess that means that if A lies in Data Segment, SEG A is the same as DS.

Correct, if DS points to Data Segment.

> does
>   MOV AX, LEA A
>   MOV DX, SEG A
>   MOV AX, [AX + DX]
>   copy the physical address of A to AX?

The last instruction is invalid, it does not exist in any of x86 CPUs. As such, this code does nothing at all. If anything, it just sits in an .asm file waiting to be corrected and assembled.

Comment: What if I used `MUL` and `ADD` instructions to multiply `DX` by 16 and add it to `AX`?

Comment: If done correctly, sure. Remember that the physical address is going to need more than 16 bits. Multiplying a 16-bit value by 16 (or equivalently, shifting it 4 positions left) makes it 20-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It copies the **content** of AX + DX address (which is A) to AX.

```
MOV AX, LEA A ; Copy A offset to AX
MOV DX, SEG A ; Copy A segment to DX
MOV AX, [AX + DX] ; Copy A to AX
```

Comment: Oh yes. I missed the dereferencing. Thank you. So the 2nd line does "Copy content of DS register to DX" ?

Comment: Yes, I assume so from your question. Never used TASM and never seen that `SEG` directive. You can debug to make sure.

Comment: `mov ax, [ax + dx]` is just going to make your assembler vomit - there's no such instruction! An address (in 16-bit mode) is the value in segreg * 16 + offset.

Comment: @FrankKotler, ah, yes, my bad. I didn't test this code. So, if I want to do that, I will HAVE to use a `MUL` and an `ADD` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

SEG provides the operand segment. If the variable segment is referenced by no segment register, you can use SEG. But otherwise you should use LEA, LDS. 
example:

```
 .data
```

var db ?
     .code
x db ?

start:
...

for var SEG is DS and for x SEG is CS, their segment addresses.