# What is 'seg cs' in bootsect.s

Tags: linux, maven-assembly-plugin

I read bootsect.s(linux-0.11).

```
mov dl, #0x00

mov ax, # #0x0800

int 0x13

**seg cs**

mov sectors, cs
```

....

I don't know '`seg cs`'.

What is meaning '`seg cs`'?

Comment: _"seg es is a directive that tells the assembler which segment...code/data etc. is affected by the instructions that follow it."_

Comment: And maybe helpful, but not sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528646/what-does-seg-directive-do-in-8086.